# Possible null pointer exception in string utils

Tags: java, apache-stringutils

I am using commons StringUtils.isNotBlank() to check if a string is not empty and blank. In some scenarios for a blank string or a null as input validation is not happening as expected. Null or blank is getting through.

```
   if( StringUtils.isNotEmpty(obj.getvalue()) ){
        .............
    }
```

When I go through the [documentation of StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) I found,

> A side effect of the null handling is that a NullPointerException
>   should be considered a bug in StringUtils (except for deprecated
>   methods).

What dose it mean? It has got anything to do with my scenario?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you have any code examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In some scenarios for a blank string or a null as input validation is not happening as expected. Null or blank is getting through.

Either there is a bug in your validation logic, or you have data coming from a source that has not been subjected to validation.

If you posted the actual code and the NPE stacktrace, we could help you find it.

---

> What does it mean?

It means that if `StringUtils.isNotBlank()` throws an NPE, then there is a bug in the method.  (The "side effect" that the javadoc is talking about is a *logical* side-effect; i.e. a secondary logical consequence of the way that the API is defined.)

> It has got anything to do with my scenario?

It has nothing to do with it ... unless a call to `StringUtils.isNotBlank()`*is* throwing an NPE.

---

**UPDATE**

Considering your example code (tweaked for illustrative purposes):

```
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(obj.getvalue())){
    String s = obj.getvalue();
    if (s == null) {
        System.err.println("Ooops!!");
    }
}
```

I can think of a number of scenarios in which this code could either give an NPE or cause "Ooops!" to be printed.  For instance:

1. If `obj` is `null` then an NPE will definitely be thrown.  This could happen before you called `isNotEmpty`, or (if the value of the `obj` variable can be changed can be changed) in the "then" block.
2. It is possible that the `getValue` method could throw an NPE.
3. It is possible (but unlikely) that calling `getValue` has a side-effect that causes it to change the state of `obj` and return a different value (e.g. `null`) on the 2nd call.   Ooops!
4. It is possible that some other thread is changing the state of the `obj` object while the current thread is executing the above code.   Ooops!

Most of these problems could be "fixed" as follows:

```
String s = obj.getvalue();
if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(s)){ // No NPE possible here now
    if (s == null) {
        System.err.println("Ooops!!");  // Cannot happen now.
    }
}
```

Comment: I am running in a multithreaded environment. My scenario occurs once in a while. I am interested in the side effect that is present in the StringUtils documentation...

Comment: It is not a side effect in that sense.  It is a **logical** side-effect; i.e. a logical consequence of the way that the API has been designed.

Answer (score 4):

Read the sentence above the one you quoted:

> StringUtils handles null input Strings quietly. That is to say that a
>   null input will return null. Where a boolean or int is being returned
>   details vary by method.
>
> A side effect of the null handling is that a NullPointerException
>   should be considered a bug in StringUtils (except for deprecated
>   methods).

So since it handles null values it shouldn't throw NullPointerExceptions.

And if you check out the method, `isNotBlank`, you'll find this table:

```
 StringUtils.isNotBlank(null)      = false
 StringUtils.isNotBlank("")        = false
 StringUtils.isNotBlank(" ")       = false
 StringUtils.isNotBlank("bob")     = true
 StringUtils.isNotBlank("  bob  ") = true
```

if you are receiving other values you are indeed experiencing a bug, which you should report. But it is more likely that the NPE is caused by something else. Maybe some other StringUtils method returned null, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For an in detail examination of your problem, you could post a specific example where the code goes wrong in your opinion.

**StringUtils Behaviour**

- StringUtils.isNotBlank(null) returns false
- StringUtils.isNotBlank("") returns false
- StringUtils.isNotBlank("  ") returns false
- StringUtils.isNotBlank(" testvalue") returns true

If the behaviour is anything else, this is a bug in the libary

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that NPE is thrown from `obj.getvalue()` as StringUtils.isNotBlank() will never throw a NPE.
If you are running your code in a multi-threaded environment you can make your method synchronized so it prevents simultaneous access to your method from multiple sources.

For more help can you send your `stack trace` or `code block`?

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a bug either in the `StringUtils.isNotBlank()` method or in the documentation. If you pass a `null` to `isNotBlank()` it will toss a `NullPointerException` which is contrary to the documentation. Thus one or the other (code or documentation) is incorrect.

Here's a good replacement using Guave from: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074361/core-java/checking-for-null-or-empty-or-white-space-only-string-in-java.html